# Naming Main class for Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, class

Just a real quick and simple question:

The original class when making an android app is called "MainActivity".  Will I have any issues if I rename it "Main"?

(In my research, I see that it can be renamed, but I am unsure if this will create complications to give it the name "Main".  I wanted to ask before messing up my program and digging myself into a hole.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't see why you wouldn't keep it at MainActivity, it's not that much more to type :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, no problem. There are a few things to keep in mind, though:

- All references to `MainActivity` must reroute to `Main`.
- All references in the manifest for the main activity (the one to launch) must be changed to `Main`. (Pay most attention to `<activity android:name="..." .../>`.)
- Anyone currently using your app will lose the shortcut in their launcher if you change the main activity class name.
- `MainActivity` is more descriptive--I'd honestly keep it like that.

I would recommend you read [this Google developer blog about "What You Can't Change"](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html).

Comment: excellent answer and thanks for the resource!  if i changed the name, when i uploaded the app again, wouldnt that fix any shortcut issues for users?

Comment: @SamuelKnox No, changing it at all removes the shortcut from their launcher, until they re-add it. This is because Android cannot find the launcher intent that was specified in the manifest, so it gets rid of the shortcut.

Comment: i see. so basically, i never want to change my main activity's name after the app has been released?

Comment: thanks for the help eric. i could not have received a better answer!

Comment: @SamuelKnox That's correct--Evernote and a few other big-name apps have done it before and received a handful of somewhat negative reviews for disappearing shortcuts. Glad I could help! :)